# How to expose object fields to make accessible on reports?

Tags: lightning, custom-object, data, fields, custom-reports

I have a custom object in Order Management. I wanted a field within the object to appear on my Order report in reports. I couldn’t find the field in my field options. Anyone got any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Are these fields added to report type?

Comment: How do I do that? I made them all visible from the check boxes.

Answer (score 0):

What is the relation from your custom object to Order? You either need a custom report type to add it via relationship, or you can create a formula field to pull it over to the Order level. The best way to solve this depends on how these objects are related, though.

Comment: It’s shipped and tracking number